# Selenium's WebDriver.execute_script() returns 'None'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My program is having trouble getting an existing class from a webpage using Selenium. It seems that my WebDriver.execute_script function is not working.

```
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver

#Path to the chromedriver is definitely working fine.
path_to_chromedriver = 'C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Coding\FreeFoodFinder\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
url = 'http://www.maidservicetexas.com/'
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
browser.get(url)
content = browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('content')");
#Just printing the first character of the returned content's toString for now. Don't want the whole thing yet.
#Only ever prints 'N', the first letter of 'None'...so obviously it isn't finding the jsgenerated content even after waiting.
print content
```

My program returns 'None,' which tells me that the javascript function is not returning a value/being executed. Chrome's web dev tools tell me that 'content' is certainly a valid class name. The webpage isn't even dynamically generated (my eventual goal is to scrape dynamic content, which is why I make my WebDriver wait for 30 seconds before running the script.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Return** the value:

```
content = browser.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('content');");
```

Comment: I knew the answer to this question would make me feel stupid. Thank you so much alecxe!